# Get Client's IP Address Using NCAT

Tags: iptables, netcat, honeypot

I'm participating in a computer security competition this weekend and I'm trying to make a script that will block an IP address for 5 minutes if I get port scanned.  So I decided I could use NCAT and have it execute a iptables script if someone tries to connect to a port I am listening to.  The problem is, I don't know how to get the IP address of the client that is connecting.  Is this possible to do?

I don't want to use honeypots because they can be detected by many scanners, and any custom scripts I have, I have to write when I'm in the competition room.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most portscans won't do a full tcp handshake, they will run a syn scan. So netcat would never recieve a connection. I recommend psad. On debian systems you can get it with:

```
aptitude install psad
```

Also, such a question should be asked at https://security.stackexchange.com/